# Help understanding mongodb explain results

Tags: index, mongodb, explain

I have an index on field f1. `{f1:1}`

Running an explain on the following query

```
db.coll.find()
```

says that the winning plan is a CollScan (expected)

However, for `db.coll.find().sort({f1:1})`

the explain says

```
"stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
```

I have trouble understanding this because even though the index is used for sorting , shouldn't it have done a collection scan to fetch the documents that needed to be sorted?

Thank you

Comment: What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have trouble understanding this because even though the index is used for sorting , shouldn't it have done a collection scan to fetch the documents that needed to be sorted?

If you fully iterate both of your queries they will end up fetching all documents from the collection, but they take different approaches in terms of query planning and execution.

A *collection scan* means an index was not used and documents were retrieved in [natural order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-in-natural-order) (which is the undefined "order of documents on disk"). An *index scan* indicates an index was used regardless of whether that stage returns some or all documents in a collection.

If you review the full query explain output for a collection scan you should see `totalKeysExamined` is 0 and `totalDocsExamined` equal to the number of documents returned.

> db.coll.find().explain('executionStats')

The  `winningPlan` for your first query should be a simple `COLLSCAN` stage:

```
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "direction" : "forward"
    }
```

> db.coll.find().sort({f1:1}).explain('executionStats')

In your second query example the [index supports the requested sort order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/), so you should see `totalKeysExamined` and `totalDocsExamined` are equal to the number of documents returned (assuming that `f1` is not not a [multikey (array) index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey)).

The `winningPlan` for this should be an index scan (`IXSCAN`) which iterates the `f1` index in sorted order to fetch matching documents. You should see the `IXSCAN` as the `inputStage` for a `FETCH`:

```
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "f1" : 1
            },
            ...
    }
```

If the winning plan did *not* support the requested sort order, you would still see an `IXSCAN` or `COLLSCAN` but it would be part of an in-memory `SORT` stage ([limited to ~32MB of documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sort-Operations)):

```
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "SORT",
        "sortPattern" : {
            "f1" : 1
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    ... 
                },
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```